# Export MySQL Workbench model to SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, mysql-workbench

I am working on a database design in MySQL Workbench and would like to use SQLite to make a small demo. I am looking for a way to export my model into SQLite files with tables & relationships set up.

I tried this plugin (https://github.com/tatsushid/mysql-wb-exportsqlite) but it seems that it is not working anymore.

Any suggestions?